# How to install third HDD into existing RAID setup?

Tags: windows-xp, raid

i have a WinXP machine currently setup with two HDD in a RAID configuration.  I want to add a third drive to the system just to increase the available HDD space.  This third drive is much larger than the RAID and other two HDDs.  All three drives are SATA drives.  I have installed the third drive and it seems to show up/detected by the Raid s/w, but it does not show up in Windows.

Is it possible to set this third drive up as an independent drive?  Do I need to some how configure it in the RAID setup?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure it in the RAID setup as an independent disk; then it'll show up in Windows.

It would really help if you filled in some details, like what kind of RAID card you have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Chris.  I don't know any of those details at the moment, but I'll go figure it out.